# angular/cli and TypeScript version compilation error

Tags: typescript, highcharts, angular5

I'm upgrading my project to angular5.

in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {    
   "highcharts-export-csv": "git+https://github.com/highcharts/export-csv.git"
 }
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~5.1.2",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
}
```

It works, but I got a warning:

> @angular/compiler-cli@5.1.2 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.6.0' but 2.6.2 was found instead.
> Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.
> Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.
> `npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.6.0'`
> To disable this warning run "ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".

So, I changed my TypeScript version to 2.5.3 but now I have compilation error, which I haven't when cli and TypeScript versions didn't match.

It's a long error, but if I am not wrong here is the key:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/myCsv/myCsv.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'highcharts-export-csv' in '/myRoute/myCsv'
resolve 'highcharts-export-csv' in '/myRoute/src/app/myCsv'
Parsed request is a module
using description file: /myRoute/package.json (relative path: ./src/app/myCsv)
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
 after using description file: /myRoute/package.json (relative path: ./src/app/myCsv)
resolve as module
```

Comment: I can't understand how but installing 2.6.2 typescript version, works and the warning is not shown. Can I ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the TS warning from the Angular CLI with

```
ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false
```

Comment: Ok, that's in the warning I pasted, I suppose it's better solve than ignore, and I prefer use compatible version in my dependencies. Thank you anyway!